# Bijection between sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A= \{$ $F$ $|$ $F$ $:$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $\}$.

Prove that a bijection does not exist between $A$ $and$ $\mathbb{R}$

The idea I have is to show that a bijection between $A$ $and$ $P(\mathbb{R})$ exists. This is because if $A\sim$ $P(\mathbb{R})$ and since no bijection between $P(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$ exists, then no bijection could exist between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

However, im not sure what bijection to set up. What could I do? any hints?

The idea I had was to set up a bijection $f: P(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow A$ to be  defined as $f(A)=g_A$ where $g_A : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow A$
However, i'm not on the right track, as the map I attempted to construct is not well defined.

Comment: A possible approach would be showing $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have different cardinalities.

Comment: @David If $A$ is uncountable then either $A$ $\sim$ $\mathbb{R}$ $or$ $A\sim P(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You can't say that without further assumptions. There are other possible cardinalities.

Comment: @David I know that I can't assume it, I meant to ask if whether its a correct statement or not.

Comment: Look at [Beth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number), what you've listed is just $\beth_1$ and $\beth_2$. The cardinalities $\beth_i, i\geq 3$, are distinct and also uncountable.

Comment: FWIW it took me a few readings to figure out how to parse those two colons.  I think in context $\{F|F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R\}$ might be easier to read.

Comment: Note that all you need is an *injection* from $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ to $A$. Then $|A|\ge|\mathcal P(\mathbb R)|>|\mathbb R|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you just need a way to define $g_A:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Try
$$g_A(x) =\begin{cases} 1&\mbox{ if } x\in A\\0&\mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, no problem.